# Structure of AddIns in MVC-projects

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure, mvc

We are moving an SP2013-onprem-solution to SP Online and Azure (provider hosted). Our Web Parts and Pages will be addins in on or more MVC-projects.
There will also be some (Azure Web) jobs, setup-code that creates the site structure. This would make ~7 addins, but will probably get more in the future.

If Im correct, in Azure you deploy one MVC-project(=MVC-site) to one Web App, 
the web apps are unlimited and have no extra cost if you are running B,S or P-service plans (which we do).

**So my question is:** What project structure is recommended, theses are my thoughts (shared logic in dlls in all below)

1. Everything in one MVC-project, each of add-ins are separated by areas

   - Simple release, one click
   - It feels like its going to be cluttered
2. One MVC-project per AddIn.

   - You can release a single add-in/add a new one, without having to do a full release
   - If you are releasing a change with common logic, you probably have to release and test all/many other component as well (but thats the case every time in (1)
3. One per choice in the "top menu". Today the VS-projects are structured that way (one wsp per top menu choice)

This feels like a trade off between the two?

I would really appreciate any feedback from anyone that have some long time experience with SP online and Azure. Or am I totally thinking the wrong way here?

One per "Main site" (in essence, one per menu choice in top menu, where each top menu choice is a web)